# Biblatex prints white space plus period before PART field

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

When I print the bibliography with a BOOK entry using the PART field, biblatex prints white space followed by a period before the PART field is printed. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        sorting = nyt,
        sortcites = false,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{smith1965,
    AUTHOR = "John Smith",
    LOCATION = "London",
    NUMBER = "3",
    PART = "Part one",
    PUBLISHER = "Johnson Press",
    SERIES = "Classic books",
    TITLE = "A good book",  
    YEAR = "1965"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \parencite{smith1965}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `volume="3",PART = "1",` then you'll get in the output `3.1`

Comment: It's true it would give me the output `3.1`, but `volume` is for multi-volume books, and not for specifying the volume number in a series. For that one should use `number`. Cf. the `biblatex` manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BibLaTeX defines the directive to print the part as `\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{.#1}`

You can change it by

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{#1}
```

The BibLaTeX manual specifies:

> `part` field (literal)
>
> The number of a partial volume. This field applies to books only, not to journals. It may be used when a logical volume consists of two or more physical ones. In this case the number of the logical volume goes in the volume field and the number of the part of that volume in the part field. See also volume.

Here is a redefinition of the printing directive that maintains consistency with BibLaTeX

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{%
    \iffieldundef{volume}
        {#1}
        {.#1}%   
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this. This says "If the entry has nothing in the field ``VOLUME``, then print the field ``PART`` as is. If the entry does have something in the field ``VOLUME``, then print the field ``PART`` with a period before it"? Do I put this in the preamble in my .tex file?

Comment: @Sverre Yes, your understanding is correct. Put it in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful approach, and works like a charm.