# Character strings in biblatex's PART and VOLUME fields

Tags: biblatex

When the `PART` and `VOLUME` fields in a bibliographic entry are numerals, `biblatex` puts out something very reasonable (see below). But when these fields are character strings, which they often are for foreign languages, `biblatex`'s output is less desirable. In this case, for instance, it shouldn't print `Vol.`, since this information is contained in the following string (the word `bolken`), and whatever comes in `PART` should be printed with a space after the period, i.e.:

> Skulerud, Olai (1938b). *Tinnsmålet*. Fyrste bolken: Ljodlære. Andre bandet. Oslo: Olaf Norli.

In short, I would like to add something to my `.tex` preamble that says the following:

"When the field `volume` doesn't begin with a numeral, print the field as it is (no word `Vol.`)".

and

"When the field `part` doesn't begin with a numeral, and there is something in the field `volume`, then print period+space+`part` after `volume`".

I should mention that I already have something in my preamble referring to `VOLUME` and `PART`, as addressed in [Biblatex prints white space plus period before PART field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83395/biblatex-prints-white-space-plus-period-before-part-field). It's included in the MWE below. Whatever the solution is to my current question, it shouldn't cancel out the achievement of that old tweak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{\iffieldundef{volume}{#1}{.#1}}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{skulerud1938a,
    AUTHOR = "Olai Skulerud",
    TITLE = "Tinnsmålet",
    YEAR = "1938",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    PART = "2",
    PUBLISHER = "Olaf Norli",
    VOLUME = "1"}
@BOOK{skulerud1938b,
    AUTHOR = "Olai Skulerud",
    TITLE = "Tinnsmålet",
    YEAR = "1938",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    PART = "Andre bandet",
    PUBLISHER = "Olaf Norli",
    VOLUME = "Fyrste bolken: Ljodlære"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{skulerud1938a}{skulerud1938b}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about placing `Fyrste bolken: Ljodlære` in the `Titleaddon`-field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` has `\ifinteger`, `\ifnumeral` and `\ifnumerals` tests. Thus if the field `part` is an integer (or a range of integers, i.e., 45--72 or "1, 2, 3", even in different representation), one can achieve the desired effect with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {#1}
    {\ifnumerals{#1}
      {.#1}
      {\adddot\addspace#1}}%
  }
```

For the more general case where `part` begins with a number, then one can use the `xstring` package and modify the above code as follows:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {#1} 
    {\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\FirstOfPart]%
       \IfInteger{\FirstOfPart}%
         {.#1}
         {\adddot\addspace#1}}%
  }
```

EDIT: The same technique can be used for removing the "Vol." prefix in case the field `volume` is not a number (or numeral)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{%
  \ifnumerals{#1}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace#1}{#1}%
}
```

Caveat, it does not cover the case where a number is spelled out, i.e., "two".

Comment: I've tested this, and it takes care of my question related to PART. But what do I do to fix the VOLUME issue?

Comment: @Guido You might replace `\addspace` with `~` in order to avoid that the number of the volume gets on a new line (as it was the problem in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248036/issue-with-breaking-spaces-for-bibliography).