# Biblatex: Don't print 'Vol' when the string in the VOLUME field doesn't begin with a numeral

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow-up to [Character strings in biblatex's PART and VOLUME fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103480/character-strings-in-biblatexs-part-and-volume-fields). The answer provided there covered most of what I asked for, but it left out the specification "begin" in:

"When the field `volume` doesn't begin with a numeral, print the field as it is (no word `Vol.`)".

The suggested solution was to add the following to the preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\ifnumerals{#1}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace#1}{#1}}
```

But this will not print the word `Vol.` in the cases where the the `volume` field begins with a numeral, and then contains non-numeric characters afterwards. I would like it to do that. Below a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\ifnumerals{#1}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace#1}{#1}}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{hogg1992,
    AUTHOR = "Richard M. Hogg",
    TITLE = "A grammar of Old English",
    YEAR = "1992",
    LOCATION = "Oxford",
    PUBLISHER = "Blackwell",
    VOLUME = "1: Phonology"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{hogg1992}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of tinkering with the `volume` field format, I'd rather use the standard way to cite individual volumes of a multi-volume work: put "Phonology"  in the `title`  field and "A grammar of Old English" in the `maintitle` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{hogg1992,
    AUTHOR = "Richard M. Hogg",
    MAINTITLE = "A grammar of Old English",
    YEAR = "1992",
    LOCATION = "Oxford",
    PUBLISHER = "Blackwell",
    VOLUME = "1",
    TITLE = "Phonology"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree. I should add, though, that some tinkering with the ``volume`` field is needed, as when it contains character strings in other languages. But in those cases I can go with the solution given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103480/character-strings-in-biblatexs-part-and-volume-fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\def\tmp##1##2{\ifinteger{##1}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace##1##2}{##1##2}}\expandafter\tmp#1}
```

should yield the desired result. Note the use of `\ifinteger` instead of `\ifnumerals`, as with the latter the letter V in "Volume Phonology" would be interpreted as roman numeral and not as character.

EDIT: lockstep's answer is probably the better way to go.