# Issue with breaking spaces for bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm using xelatex, biblatex and biber

When I make bibliography with `\printbibliography`, it may break lines for common elements like initials or volume numbers or so (see example below).

I want to have a non-breaking space in Vol.~1 and all other similar stuff, like "no. 2"

Solution like setting up `volume={Vol.~1}` in bib file is not what I want because it can make printing area overflow and its unlikely to manually rewrite all entries

I am newbie in LaTeX. Is there an easy solution?

**UPDATE: MWE**

Here is a MWE for my issue. I specially deleted some characters from title so you can see how it looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=3,
    style=gost-numeric,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{manning2008introduction,
        title={Introduction to informati},
        author={Manning, Christopher D and Raghavan, Prabhakar and Sch{\"u}tze, Hinrich},
        volume={1},
        publisher={Cambridge university press Cambridge}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{manning2008introduction}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

result
[image]

Comment: Can you please construct a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? From the standard definitions in `biblatex.def` what you want should already be implemented. (The definition for `volume` is for example `\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}` with a non-breaking space between "volume" and your number.) So something else must be going on here.

Comment: Added MWE and attached a screenshot of the result. As you wrote about standard definition, I think that biblatex-gost might corrupt this behavior

Comment: Indeed, it was just a matter of seconds to identify the culprit with you MWE (I'm slightly exaggerating, it was a matter of a few minutes). The magic of an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After abbreviated bibstrings `biblatex-gost` uses the command `\addabbrvspace` for spacing.

This spacing uses the `abbrvpenalty` penalty, described in `biblatex.def` by

```
% The counter 'abbrvpenalty' holds the penalty used in short or
% abbreviated bibliography strings. For example, a linebreak in
% expressions such as "et al." or "ed. by" is unfortunate, but should
% still be possible to prevent overfull boxes. We use TeX's
% \hyphenpenalty (normally 50) as the default value. The idea is
% making TeX treat the whole expression as if it were a single,
% hyphenatable word as far as line-breaking is concerned. If you
% dislike such linebreaks, use a higher value. If you do not mind
% them at all, set this counter to zero. If you want to suppress them
% unconditionally, set it to 10000.
\defcounter{abbrvpenalty}{\hyphenpenalty}
```

So you could set `\defcounter{abbrvpenalty}{10000}` (this helps in your example, smaller values did not seem to do any good).

If you, however, do not agree that this is a case for `abbrvpenalty` (normally `\addabbrvspace` seem to be only used within one string such as `et\addabbrvspace al\adddot`), you might prefer the standard `\addnbspace` (that is `~`, or its thin version `\addnbthinspace`) here, you would then need to redefine `gost-standard.bbx`'s definitions as follows

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
  \iffieldnum{volume}
    {\ifbibstring{volume}
      {\bibstring{volume}\addnbspace#1}
      {}}
    {\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{%
  \ifbibstring{volume}
    {\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace#1}
    {}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=3,
    style=gost-numeric,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{manning2008introduction,
        title={Introduction to informati},
        author={Manning, Christopher D. and Raghavan, Prabhakar and Sch{\"u}tze, Hinrich},
        volume={1},
        publisher={Cambridge University Press},
        location = {Cambridge},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
      \iffieldnum{volume}
        {\ifbibstring{volume}
          {\bibstring{volume}\addnbspace#1}
          {}}
        {\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}\isdot}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{%
      \ifbibstring{volume}
        {\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace#1}
        {}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{manning2008introduction}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: DeclareFieldFormat saved my bibliography, thank you a lot!