# Line breaking prevention immediately afrer bibstring in biblography

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I'm trying to make a bibliography with BibLaTeX. The problem is that I don't know how to force BibLaTeX to move the key word "W" (in) to the beginning of the next line:
[image]

A bit similar problem was solved here: [keeping together "vol." word and volume number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248036/issue-with-breaking-spaces-for-bibliography), but I can't adopt this solution to my case (using BibLaTeX package documentation).
My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage[
    style=numeric,
    firstinits=true,        % display only first letter of a name
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@article{dindorf2003,
    author =    {Dindorf, Ryszard},
    title =     {Musku\l{}y pmeumatyczne. {Charakterystyki} dynamiczne},
    journal =   {Pneumatyka},
    year =      {2003},
    number =    {5/42},
    pages =     {40-42}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{dindorf2003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The punctuation after the `W` (translation of `In`) is provided by `\intitlepunct`.  By default this command is `\addcolon\space`, you can redefine it to have a non-breaking space via

```
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage[
    style=numeric,
    firstinits=true,        % display only first letter of a name
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@article{dindorf2003,
    author =    {Dindorf, Ryszard},
    title =     {Musku\l{}y pmeumatyczne. {Charakterystyki} dynamiczne},
    journal =   {Pneumatyka},
    year =      {2003},
    number =    {5/42},
    pages =     {40-42}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}
\begin{document}

\nocite{dindorf2003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```