# Moving short bibstring to the next line of footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I am using BibLaTeX with command `\footcite` - to put bibliography data into footnotes. I'd like to avoid placing short key word "W:" (translation of "In:") at the end of line.
The line `\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}` has impact only on content of bibliography placed by the use of command `\printbibliography` (see: [Line breaking prevention immediately afrer bibstring in biblography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350568/line-breaking-prevention-immediately-afrer-bibstring-in-biblography)).

[image]

According to BibLaTeX package documentation (page 106) counters`highnamepenalty` and `lownamepenalty` can be set to prevent line breaking between initial name letter and surname (?). Is any other way to position name initial (together with the word "i" - translation of "and") in the the same line as surname? I tried to set `\setcounter{highnamepenalty}{10000}` and `\setcounter{lownamepenalty}{0}`, but without expected effect.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@inbook{gumplowicz2010,
    author =    {Gumplowicz, L.},
    title =     {O naturalnym prawie kształtowania się państw},
    booktitle = {Dwa życia Ludwika Gumplowicza. Wybór tekstów},
    editor =    {Mozetič, G. and Surman, J.},
    editortype =    {redactor},
    location =  {Warszawa},
    year =      {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\setlength{\textwidth}{115mm}

\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}    % has no impact on output

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{gumplowicz2010}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress a line break between the name initials and the last name you need to set `lownamepenalty`. `highnamepenalty` is for different bits of the same name part, so it would separate two first names. So you need

```
\defcounter{lownamepenalty}{10000}
```

to suppress a line break in 'J. Surman'. But you also want to tie the 'i' to the 'J. Surman', so additionally you need

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\nobreakspace}
```

The original definition has `\space` instead of `\nobreakspace` here.

For the 'W:' the story is a bit more interesting. In fact

```
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}
```

does the right thing, but because `\intitlepunct` is handled a bit differently from other punctuation its effects are negated. You can fix this with

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}}
```

Incidentally, using `@incolletion` (which is *probably* the correct entry type here anyway) instead of `@inbook` does not make the different handling of `\intitlepunct` apparent.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{gumplowicz2010,
  author     = {Gumplowicz, L.},
  title      = {O naturalnym prawie kształtowania się państw},
  booktitle  = {Dwa życia Ludwika Gumplowicza. Wybór tekstów},
  editor     = {Mozetič, G. and Surman, J.},
  editortype = {redactor},
  location   = {Warszawa},
  year       = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setlength{\textwidth}{115mm}

\defcounter{lownamepenalty}{10000}

\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\nobreakspace}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\nobreakspace}

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{gumplowicz2010}.
\end{document}
```

[image]